# 'NoneType' object is not iterable in Chartit

Tags: python, django

So, I am trying to create a pivot chart with my data but I keep getting the 'NoneType' object is not iterable. I am using Chartit. My error is specifically with 'terms': ['tot_ft']}]) this is specifically in the PivotChart part

Here is my code:
Here are the following things I have imported:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_list_or_404, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from basketball.models import Stats, Player, League, Game, Team
from django.contrib.auth import get_user
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from chartit import PivotDataPool, PivotChart
```

views.py

```
def player_pivot_chart_view(request):
# Step 1: Create a PivotDataPool with the data we want to retrieve 
playerPivotData = PivotDataPool(
        series = 
        [{'options': {
            'source': Stats.objects.all(),
            'categories': 'player__first_name'},
        'terms': {
                'tot_ft':Sum('freeThrowsMade')}}])
pivcht = PivotChart(
            datasource = playerPivotData,
            series_options = [
                {'options': {
                    'type': 'column',
                    'stacking': True},
                'terms': ['tot_ft']}])
return render(request,'basketball/StatsPage.html', {'dataChart':pivcht})
```

models.py

```
class Stats(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    freeThrowsMade = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='FTm', default = 0)
    freeThrowsAttempted = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='FTa', default = 0)
    twoPointsMade = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='2Pm', default = 0)
    twoPointsAttempted = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='2Pa', default = 0)
    threePointsMade = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='3Pm', default = 0)
    threePointsAttempted = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='3Pa', default = 0)
    blocks = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    steals = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    assists = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
    fouls= models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0)
```

Comment: Can you also add the traceback

Comment: You can go to this link http://dpaste.com/1073522/

Comment: I have a question Sum of a single field should give 1 data point and you just have one single term/axis on which you are charting this out , what are you trying to chart out with a single data point. You have to have more relative positions to create  a chart.

Comment: I am trying to create a pivot table of the sum of each players free Throws made. With the code I have right now, won't it separate it by players and take the sum of all their free throws made

Comment: I don't know pivot chart but I would think that you probably need to check more about the data points although I think you should get a ValueError instead . I am not too sure you have shared the whole traceback

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. After a little search in chartit source code, I found the solution.

There is a optional argument you can give to `PivotChart` constructor, besides `data_source` and `series_options`: `chart_options`. When chart_options is not given, chartit assign `None` to it by default, causing the error you got.
This is actually a bug in chartit.

To bypass this, you should send a empty dictionary as `chart_options`:

```
pivcht = PivotChart(
            datasource = playerPivotData,
            series_options = [
                {'options': {
                    'type': 'column',
                    'stacking': True},
                'terms': ['tot_ft']}],
            chart_options = {})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and the way I knew something was going wrong was by sending the data to one template. I was putting the data from the chart on my "base.html. and every time i open a template that was not the one receiving the data, I got that error. Make sure you are not doing that.